# What is the correct way of using extern for global variables?

Tags: c++, extern

file a.cc

```
int a = 0;
```

file b.cc

```
#include "a.cc"
```

file main.cc

```
#include "b.cc"
extern int a;

int main() {


}

g++ -c a.cc
g++ -c b.cc
g++ main.cc a.o b.o
error: multiple definitions of a
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In general you shouldn't ever be `#include`ing `.cc` files, only `.h` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You include a `.cc` (or `.cpp`) files, which is wrong. Do not do that. You need a header, and in that put the `extern int a;`:

```
// a.h
// include guards omitted
extern int a;

// a.cc
#include "a.h"

int a;

// b.cc
#include "a.h"

// main.cc
#include "a.h"

int main(){
  // use a
}
```

Comment: @Mark: That shouldn't happen, do you have all the files like shown? Are you maybe compiling the `.h` files? If yes, don't do that, only compile the `.cc` files.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing exactly what the linker said: You are providing multiple definitions of 'a'. Both a.cc and b.cc are defining the variable 'a' as something with external linkage.

Don't do that!

Don't #include a source file. There are times when you do want to do that, but then again, there are times when you want to use `goto`.

Comment: all three files need to manipulate the variable. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: _Declare_ the variable wherever you need it, preferably by #including a file that declares it. _Define_ the variable once, and only once. Failure to do so is a violation of the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the compiler tells you -- you end up **defining** `a` in all three translation units! You want it the other way around: The repeatedly included **declaration** should be extern, and there must only be *one* definition. For instance:

```
// header: stuff.h
extern int a;
void foo();
```

```
// first TU: a.cpp
#include "stuff.h"

void foo() { a += 1; }
```

```
// second TU: main.cpp
#include "stuff.h"

int a; // `a` is stored in this TU

int main() {
  a = 6;
  foo();
  //  now a == 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the include, imagine placing all the files into one file.  That is basically what the compiler sees because everything was included by the preprocessor before the compiler stage.

So your main.cc starts looking like this.

```
int a;
extern int a;
```

The compiler considers this okay because extern without an initializer is just a declaration so memory is not allocated for it.  "int a" is a definition, however, so main.o includes instructions for allocating memory for a.

Once you link it, the linker notices that a.o and b.o already has "a" defined as well.  "a" because this is where it was originally defined and "b" because b included "a" which had the definition.

To fix this, just take out #include "b.cc" in main.cc.  In fact, take out b.cc entirely because there is no point in it.

If you really want to do this right, create a separate header for "a" called a.h with extern int a.  Then main.cc and b.cc are free to include a.h without redefining a.