# How to declare global variable in this situation?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way of using extern for global variables ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575791/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-extern-for-global-variables)

Sorry for repeating a similar question.

```
//object.h
object p;



//b.h
#include object.h



//b.cc
extern object p;


//c.h
#include object.h
#include b.h

//c.cc
extern object p;


//main.cc
#include c.h
extern object p;
int main() {}
```

Basically I need `c` `b` and `main`  all have access to object `p`. I also need c to have access to the methods in b and b c to have access to Object class header. What is the way to declare global variable p? The code above gives me Multiple definition error. I can't post the entire code for it would be too long, but I believe the above describes the situation well.

Comment: Sorry that post didn't fully answer my question.

Comment: Xeo's post exactly answers your question here. The only is the filenames (e.g. object.h instead of a.h).

Comment: In his answer I don't have object.cc for a.cc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the global variable in *just one* of the `.cc` files. Put its `extern` declaration in the corresponding `.h` file, and then include that file in every other `.cc` that needs to access the global variable.

In that way, the variable will be *declared* in every `.cc` (thanks to the `extern` declaration `#include`d from the `.h`), but will be *defined* only in a single `.cc`.

On the other hand, you should *never* define global variables in headers, otherwise you will get multiple definition errors during the linking (unless they had internal linkage, i.e. they were declared as `static`, but you won't ever need to have a `static` variable defined in a header).

By the way, remember to use include guards in your headers to avoid multiple definition errors during the compilation stage.